# Error in clicking on element inside <li> that lies inside <ul>

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

The HTML Code is as follows:

```html
    <li class="dropdown span pull-right username">
    <a href="#" id="username">…….</a>
    <!-- Unauthenticated : This content will only be shown to unauthenticated users-->
    <ul class="dropdown-menu signed-in-dropdown">
    <!-- Authenticated : This content will only be shown to authenticated users-->
    <li><a href="#" rel="WebClientAccount">Manage Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://content.endicia.com/ContentService/legalterms/" target="_blank">Legal Terms</a></li>                           
    <li class="lastItem"><a href="#" rel="StoreSignOut" id="signOutLink">Sign Out</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

I have to click on UserName(class="dropdown span pull-right username"). Then the dropdown menu open which has 3 options. I want to click on Sign Out (id="signOutLink)

I tried below :

```
    t=driver.find_element(By.ID ,"username")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",t) 
    time.sleep(2)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul#dropdown-menu signed-in-dropdown a[data-value='Sign Out']")))
    element.click()
```

But getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.dropdown-menu.signed-in-dropdown")))
element.click()
element2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.lastItem a#signOutLink")))
element2.click()
```

Just click to open the dropdown and proceed to click the element.

ul.dropdown-menu.signed-in-dropdown Your css selector is off. # is for ID . is for class. After you click the dropdown then proceed to click li.lastItem a#signOutLink .